# update specific value on sqllite in android

Tags: android, sqlite

```
public void updateEntry(String eMail, String password) 
{
  // Define the updated row content.
  ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();
  // Assign values for each row.

  updatedValues.put("EMAIL", eMail);
  updatedValues.put("PASSWORD", password);

  String where = "EMAIL = ?";
  db.update("LOGIN", updatedValues, where, new String[] { eMail });
}
```

I have to update my password only (I created four fields name, password, email, phone). Is this okay?

Comment: if you only want to change your password then you don't need to do this for your email. you can delete this line  updatedValues.put("EMAIL", eMail);

Comment: For the rest, if the EMAIL is unique, yes this seems correct (if you take xFighter advice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update password into database based on input mail_id.. can use where clause for this,..